# First step with AngularJs plug-in. Browser can't load the controller's function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

Recently I've discovered AngularJS as mentioned in the title. After some lectures I'm trying to use this [plug-in](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) in order to obtain some dragNdrop feature for my web-page. I've downloaded the code from the git's master but nothing seems to work as planned. All the pages are filled with the AngularJS's syntax.

[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkGxC.png)

I've tested the example on 3 different browsers but the result is always the same. The question is: what is the missing step for a correct browser-interpretation of the code? What do I need to include in the stock files given by the owner?

Comment: Can you create a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/) with your code so we can better see what you are seeing?

Comment: If you can't create a plunk, please paste your controller code and your html so someone can help you.

Comment: So, thanks for the reply, this is the plunk with a simplified version of the test code. [link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/DaM8AiOrqE9oRnpB8xyw?p=preview). 
The test's purpose is create 2 simple lists of draggable item.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, but i think that the problem is that you're trying (according to attached screenshot) to load nested.html that is sort of "view page" (according to gihub repo), because of that there are no links to angular libs there. That's why try to include angular.js to your page or load index.html instead of nested/nested.html.
I hope my answer will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: The advice is nice, but even with the index page of the package all the code is represented as in the screenshot. In the first reply there is a comment with an useful plunk, a simplified version of the example code. Maybe with that snippet we can find the error.